# Preserve Original Filenames in Groovy Ant Task

Tags: ant, groovy

I have the following code:

```
new AntBuilder().zip( destFile: "${file}.zip" ) {
        fileset( dir: srcDir ) {
            include( name:pattern )
        }
    }
```

In this example I'd like **ant to create a zip with the same name as the original file, but with a .zip added to the end.** Is there a way to do this without knowing the original file's name ahead of time in ant? I'd like to be able to do the same thing with other ant tasks as well.

To put it another way, I'd like the filename to become whatever "pattern" resolves to for each file.

Comment: What class is the "job" object? The groovy zip task accepts strings as parameters.

Comment: My mistake, that was just a container and including it complicated the question. I've editted it out. When you say Groovy Zip Task...is that an Ant thing or a Groovy thing? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<target name="zip-files">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <dirset id="dirsToZip" dir="src">
        <include name="dir*"/>
    </dirset>

    <groovy>
        project.references.dirsToZip.each { 
            ant.zip(destfile: "${it}.zip", basedir: it)
        }
    </groovy>
</target>
```

If find the groovy task's ability to iterate thru a fileset or dirset a very useful feature.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying the only way to do this is to iterate over them all, that there's no declarative way to do it. Thank you for your help!